# Contact cursor returning duplicate rows

Tags: android, android-contacts

My application requires contacts to integrate. I am writing a query to get the contacts from the native. I get all the rows but with the duplicate rows. Duplicate are coming if Whatsapp, skype and other accounts are linked.

Below is the query

```
String isPhoneType = "(" + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            + "' AND " + CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " IS NOT NULL ) ";

    String query = Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " IS NOT NULL "
            + " AND (" + isPhoneType + ")" ;



    String[] projection;
    if (Compatibility.isCompatible(11)) {
        projection = new String[] {
                Data._ID,
                Data.CONTACT_ID,
                Data.DATA1,
                Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
                Data.PHOTO_ID,
                Data.LOOKUP_KEY,
                Data.PHOTO_URI
        };
    } else {
        projection = new String[] {
                Data._ID,
                Data.CONTACT_ID,
                Data.DATA1,
                Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
                Data.PHOTO_ID,
                Data.LOOKUP_KEY
        };
    }

    Cursor resCursor = ctxt.getContentResolver().query(uri,
            projection, query,
            null, Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

Please help in getting the unique rows based on the phone numbers.

Thanks

Comment: Please any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Add `unique` to phone number column in sqlite database and you will not get same contact twice.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_IMAGE + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: I am getting the rows from the contacts cursor not from the sqlite.